# If a timed automaton always terminates then there exists a trace with a maximum length?

Tags: automata, automata-theory

Hi I have a theoretical question regarding timed automata and I would like to know if someone has already given an answer to it, since that would be usefull for my research. So my question is the following:

Assume that you have a timed automaton that has an accepting state q_f (that has no successors) and you know that all the traces of the configuration (q,delta) (for a location q of the automaton and a clock valuation delta) always terminate, that is that they lead to q_f. Does that mean that there exists a trace of  that has a maximal length???(e.g the computation tree of (q,delta) has a finite depth)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The questions on this website should be reserved for problems specifically with programming. This seems more like strictly a math question, and may be better suited to put on Math Overflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comment! I did not know about mathoverflow.